# Laravel: I want the admin and user to go to a different pages after login

Tags: laravel

I have a frontend and backend pages. The frontend is dedicated to users, and the backend is dedicated to admins.

I want it when the user login they go to the frontend page and then when the admin login they go to the backend.

This is my route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'levelcheck:developer']], function ()
{
    // Route dashboard
    Route::get('/ec-admin/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'levelcheck:user']], function ()
{
    // Route homepage
    Route::get('/home', 'EcatalogController@home')->name('home');

});
```

This is my login form:

```
<form action="{{route('fsignin')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
</form>
```

This is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;

class EcatalogController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('frontend.signin');
    }

    public function fsignin (Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            return redirect('/home');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function fsignout (Request $request)
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return view('frontend.index');
    }
}
```

This is my middleware levelcheck:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class LevelCheck
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Auth::check()){
            return redirect()->route('signin')->with('error', 'Please login first!');
        }

        if(Auth::user()->level == 'developer'){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->level == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->level == 'user'){
            return $next($request);
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: are you using `laravel/ui` package?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your LoginController

```
class EcatalogController extends Controller
{
    protected function redirectTo(): string
    {
        if (auth()->user()->level == 'admin') {
            return '/ec-admin/dashboard';
        } elseif (auth()->user()->level == 'developer') {
            return '/home';
        }
    }
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: Please check my post, I put my controller and table for detail.

Comment: How to put developer and admin can access the dashboard page (backend), and user only could access the home page (frontend).

Comment: You have to create a middleware for that, you can post another question for that and I'll answer, OR google this *"Laravel middleware for admin and user"*.

Comment: also, mark my answer as the correct one if that helps you.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. Could you help me with this question?

Comment: What? you're asking a different question now, so I assumed the answer I posted is correct. Sorry, I can't help you I already told you what to do.